# Eclipse JPA generate entities for existing database using facet, wrong import in auto generated classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have a problem trying to generate JPA entities from existing database tabels.
My facet generate right classes but the import is wrong.
in my generated classes i have :

> import javax.persistence.*;

instead of

> import jakarta.persistence.*;

i'm using eclipse 2023-03, and i just created my springboot starter project with these dependencies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>it.danilocalzetta</groupId>
    <artifactId>ifapi</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ifapi</name>
    <description>If api</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

then i added JPA facets to my project

then i generated entities from tables
[image]

the result is:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="teams")
@NamedQuery(name="Team.findAll", query="SELECT t FROM Team t")
public class Team implements Serializable {
```

the expected result is:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="teams")
@NamedQuery(name="Team.findAll", query="SELECT t FROM Team t")
public class Team implements Serializable {
```

where can i configure the default persistence class for jpa facet?

Comment: Have you set JDK 17 in Java Build Path of your project?

Comment: yes @JoeTaras i do